# Will Experimental Data Analyst (EDA) function with Mathematica 11?

Tags: packages, commercial-package

I purchased [the add-on](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/eda/) a while back, switched computers and do not know if it is compatible with Mathematica 11. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you have already purchased the licence, why don't you just try it? You can then even self-answer your question here to let people know

Comment: I have to go through some hoops to get my download back as I don't have the files immediatelly available. I will do that once I have some free time. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just heard back from David Harrison, who is the creator of the package. He says EDA is compatible with Mathematica 11. According to him, the compatibility is not advertised because he has not gotten around to updating the documentation.

**Edit:**
I can confirm that it works wonderfully.